# Simple Window using TkInter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to `TkInter` and using Python to develop UI. So as a way of *step-by-step* learning, I'm just trying to get a window. I wrote the following simple code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("266x208")
window.title("Claculator")
```

I'm expecting an empty window that pops up when I run the code, but I get noting. Just `Process finished with exit code 0`. **What am I missing?**

PS: Python 2.7, Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't do a

```
window.mainloop()
```

at the end. Check the Tkinter docs [tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) for more help.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your code, just add `window.mainloop()`. This tells tkinter that the form is ready and it can be shown to the user.